# Project Euler #20 solution in Clojure

Tags: clojure, programming-challenge

Problem:

> \$n!\$ means \$n × (n − 1) × ... × 3 × 2 × 1\$
>
> For example, \$10! = 10 × 9 × ... × 3 × 2 × 1 = 3628800\$, and the sum of the digits in the number \$10!\$ is \$3 + 6 + 2 + 8 + 8 + 0 + 0 = 27\$.
>
> Find the sum of the digits in the number \$100!\$.

My solution in Clojure:

```
(reduce + (map (fn[x](Integer. (str x))) (seq (str (apply *' (range 1 101))))))
```

Questions:

- Is there a way to avoid the `*'` in the factorial bit? `(apply *' (range 1 101))`
- I converted the result of the factorial to a string, then to a sequence, and then mapped an Integer cast to a string cast.  Surely there must be a way to simplify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question: you could make range return a list of bigints, and reduce over it

```
(reduce * (range (bigint 1) 101))
```

your second question: :

1. you dont have to explicitly use `seq`, clojure will automatically treat your string as a seq
2. you dont have to use the full-blown string to number converter, you could for example use `int` to get the char code:

   ```
   (map #(- (int %) (int \0)) "1234")`
   ```
3. for other ways of getting digits of a number, check out this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/1dxrxgm8-z4)